# Covariant and contravariant electromagnetic field tensor transformation

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

When we go from contravariant field tensor to covariant field tensor and vice versa, what we do is basically change the electric field vector $E \Rightarrow -E$, while the magnetic fields remain the same.

What is the significance of this thing, that magnetic components are unaltered under lowering or uppering of indices? What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Generally, facts like this have no physical significance, and they hold only in one particular coordinate system, such as a Minkowski coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a matter of definition, actually. You can define a vector

\begin{align*}
x^\mu = \left(x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3\right).
\end{align*}

To "pull" the index down, you need a metric. I suppose you are working with special relativity, so you'll need the Minkowski-metric. How you define it, is basically your choice, but most people write it as

\begin{align*}
\left(\eta_{\mu\nu}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &1
\end{matrix}\right).
\end{align*}

Now, to pull the index down, you can write

\begin{align*}
x_{\nu} = x^\mu\eta_{\mu\nu} = \left(-x^0, x^1, x^2, x^3\right).
\end{align*}

and there is the minus sign you were looking for. Alternatively, you could define another Minkowski-metric

\begin{align*}
\left(\tilde{\eta}_{\mu\nu}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{matrix}\right),
\end{align*}

which would give you

\begin{align*}
x_{\nu} = x^\mu\eta_{\mu\nu} = \left(x^0, -x^1, -x^2, -x^3\right).
\end{align*}
This is still perfectly valid as long as you consistently use your convention.

Of course, if this applies to any tensor $x^\mu$, it will also apply to the electromagnetic field tensor.

Comment: Please go through the question I actually asked, this is no kind of an answer to that. I asked about the field tensor, not a general contra or covariant vector.

Comment: @user157588 This is basically the answer to your question. Depending on you sign convention for $\eta$, either the $E$ or the $B$ entries will change sign.

Comment: @user157588 this property is not specific to the electromagnetic field tensor, so I thought, it would be better to show a general case